# InDesign does not apply the paragraph styles correctly even when mapped to the same working paragraph styles

Tags: adobe-indesign

Was wondering if anyone knew why this may be happening? I've set up an InDesign document importing from Word with the correct formatting but then when I import the same document from Word with this time using the style mapping it doesn't retain and apply the styling.

I imported it - fixed all the necessary formatting issues and then made sure to save the paragraph styles for use later. I've then went back to the beginning and imported the word document again and this time used the customized style mapping to match the corresponding word styles with the now-correct InDesign styles. When I then place this document, however, it doesn't seem to retain the styling. Some styling does get transferred over but then some, such as indentation, does not.

This is it what it looks like on the correct document
[Correct image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaS0l.png)
And then when I import it again with the styles mapped to the same styles they use it doesn't work.
[Incorrect image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwZFo.png)

For example the sub heading is now numbered and indented wrong and the box on the left is now gone but it is the active applied style, with changes (I presume from the +?) If I then reapply it does work fine?

I'm not 100% sure why the paragraph style is there and works but does not seem to apply properly?

Comment: You may be better off asking this question on the [Graphic Design Stack Exchange                          ¸(https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be fixed to a degree if you perform Find/Change for all your styles:

`blank field with style` --> `blank field with the same style`

for every single paragraph style.

[image]

It can be done manually, but since we're here I'd propose this script:

```js
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var styles = doc.paragraphStyles;
var s = styles.length;

while (s--) {
    app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = '';
    app.findGrepPreferences.appliedParagraphStyle = styles[s];

    app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = '';
    app.changeGrepPreferences.appliedParagraphStyle = styles[s];

    doc.changeGrep();
}

app.findGrepPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
```

Probably the same is applied to character styles as well.